# express react js getting unauthorized from the client side fetch call

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, fetch-api

im trying to use authorization using jwt that works throughout the app front and back, except for one endpoint that gets authorized everytime i call it only from the front end.

my frontend code:

```js
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
            method: 'PUT',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
              Authentication: `Bearer ${this.state.Bearer}`,
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              id: this.state.user.id
            })
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(count =>
              this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count }))
            )
```

jwt middleware:

```js
    //authenticate access token
    function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.path)
      if (['/signin', '/register','/signout'].includes(req.path)) {
        return next();
      }
    
          const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
          console.log(authHeader, "authHeader");
          const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
          if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401)
        
          jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.sendStatus(403)
            console.log(err)
            req.user = user;
            next()
          })
        }
```

im also getting undefined authHeader in the console
would appreciate the help!

Comment: Check the network tab if token is actually getting appended to header or not, and do share the error your are getting.

Comment: @Kamran i do get the token when i check network, this is the error: 
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'U', "Unauthorized" is not valid JSON

Comment: Your error looks like you are applying any json method to string somewhere, can you please add your jwt middleware code in the question?

Comment: @Kamran added, also mentioned im getting undefined authHeader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your auth middleware is looking for "authorization" header where as from frontend you are sending the header as "Authentication", so making it "Authorization" should work.

And your "/refresh" works because you have excluded it in middleware.

Comment: now im getting: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'F', "Forbidden" is not valid JSON
sending it as authentication works for me with enother endpoint

Comment: you are getting this error on browser?

Comment: yes, on backend console im getting unfedined authHeader

Comment: can you share you /image endpoint as well and do tell which endpoint is working with authentication header?

Comment: unfedined authHeader would have gone once you updated the header as authorization, right?

Comment: i have now tried once again and it actually works, thank you!

Comment: Ideally it shouldnt work on any endpoint.

Comment: i now changed it also on the other endpoint i provided but i keep getting forbbiden for some reason

Comment: can you share code how you are using the middleware and the endpoint which is failing

Comment: im using app.use(authenticateToken) if this is what you meant.
this endpoint is made to create a new access token while im having a refresh token so maybe i get it because the access token is already expired?

Comment: it is possible.